# W8 compatible Gigabyte nVidia GeForce210, not working on W8

Tags: windows-8, graphics-card

My computer is dual booting Windows 7(32 bit) and Windows 8(64 bit).

I installed [GV-N210SL-1GI](http://ca.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3964#ov) like normal (plug it into the mother board) and then connected the monitor to it and then booted my computer. Came up with the screen asking me which OS to use so I selected Windows 7 and then I tried installing the drivers but it said it cannot find the hardware. Wasn't really bothered so I restarted the computer and instead of Windows 7 I selected Windows 8.

**EDIT:** Sometimes it doesn't even ask me what OS, Ever since I changed my default OS to windows 8 and it started using the windows 8 UI when choosing OS

It has been stuck on the loading screen (the 4 squares in the middle of the screen) for many hours and I'm not sure why its not moving past this. Can someone help me?

So far I have tried:

```
- Leaving the computer alone
- Booting in regular safe mode
- Booting in low resolution mode
- Booting with driver signed check disabled
```

None have worked.

Comment: What happens when you remove the video card and try to boot?

Comment: have you tired the latest Beta driver: http://www.nvidia.com/object/win8-win7-winvista-64bit-313.96-beta-driver.html

Comment: @PeterMaxwell It boots up normally and goes to the os selection. My default is windows 8 so it goes there using the Windows 8 interface

Comment: @magicandre1981 this would work if my OS would boot fully but it doesnt boot so i can not run the program

Comment: @Exikle How many watts is your power supply?

Comment: @PeterMaxwell it  says 140-220V? is that it, i looked at a power bar connected to the tower

Comment: I don't think that's it. It should look something like this and should be on one of the sides of your power supply: http://images10.newegg.com/NeweggImage/productimage/17-182-032-15.jpg

Comment: @PeterMaxwell oh okay found it, it says 480W

Comment: That should be enough. Use this and input everything that you have in your pc, and see what it recommends. http://www.extreme.outervision.com/psucalculatorlite.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that due to my computers age, though it was running Windows 8, it could not handle the newer video card as the voltage was too low.

I eneded up upgrading to a newer PC so I solved my problem as well as my question.